# fastest way to transpose pandas DataFrame with pd.date_range()

Tags: python, pandas

I have data frame with columns `id`, `start_dt`, `end_dt`
What is the fastest way to transform it to data frame with `id` and `dt`, where for every `id` in `dt` columns will be pd.date_range() of corresponding start and end dates? 
I tried approach via iterations from initial data frame and then pd.concat(), it is too slow

example:

initial dataframe:

```
id;  start_dt; end_dt
1 ;2019-01-01; 2019-01-03
2 ;2019-01-02; 2019-01-05
...
```

Expected dataframe:

```
id; dt
1 ; 2019-01-01
1 ; 2019-01-02
1 ; 2019-01-03
2 ; 2019-01-02
2 ; 2019-01-03
2 ; 2019-01-04
2 ; 2019-01-05
```

Comment: Can you share some of your code attempts alongside sample of the data?

Comment: @iDrwish, added sample data frames

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each row, use `pd.date_range` to create a list of date range, followed by `explode` to expand the list.

```
result = (df.set_index('id')
            .apply(lambda x:pd.date_range(x.start_dt,x.end_dt),axis=1)
            .rename('dt')
            .explode()
            .reset_index())
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need a combination of things to get this done.

1. Apply the `pd.date_range` function and `explode` to flatten it
2. Join on the original `df`
3. `reset_index`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 2, 3], 
              'start_dt': ['2019-08-01', '2019-08-03', '2019-08-05'],
              'end_dt': ['2019-08-02', '2019-08-04', '2019-08-06']
             })

df.start_dt = pd.to_datetime(df.start_dt) # Not really necessary
df.end_dt = pd.to_datetime(df.end_dt) # but good practice

time_series = (df[['start_dt', 'end_dt']]
               .apply(lambda x: pd.date_range(*x, freq='6h'), # Change the freq as needed
                      axis=1)
               .explode()
               .rename('dt') # Give the new series a name
              )

df[['id']].join(time_series).reset_index(drop=True)
```

```
    id  dt
0   1   2019-08-01 00:00:00
1   1   2019-08-01 06:00:00
2   1   2019-08-01 12:00:00
3   1   2019-08-01 18:00:00
4   1   2019-08-02 00:00:00
5   2   2019-08-03 00:00:00
6   2   2019-08-03 06:00:00
7   2   2019-08-03 12:00:00
8   2   2019-08-03 18:00:00
9   2   2019-08-04 00:00:00
10  3   2019-08-05 00:00:00
11  3   2019-08-05 06:00:00
12  3   2019-08-05 12:00:00
13  3   2019-08-05 18:00:00
14  3   2019-08-06 00:00:00
```

I chose my own time instances and `freq` but feel free to change it to whatever suits your needs.

Answer (score 1):

i am doing a [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html#pandas.DataFrame.melt) followed by a [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`resample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html):

```
x=df.melt('id',value_name='dt').drop('variable',1)
x=x.set_index('dt').groupby('id').apply(lambda x : 
                            x.resample('D').ffill()).reset_index(level=1)
x.reset_index(drop=True)
```

---

```
          dt  id
0 2019-01-01   1
1 2019-01-02   1
2 2019-01-03   1
3 2019-01-02   2
4 2019-01-03   2
5 2019-01-04   2
6 2019-01-05   2
```

Comment: This method will not produce correct results if there are several rows with the same id, for example when
 df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 1, 2], 
              'start_dt': ['2019-08-01', '2019-08-05', '2019-08-10'],
              'end_dt': ['2019-08-03', '2019-08-07', '2019-08-12']
             })